# Can I find and replace multiple field codes with plain text, while retaining the value that the field refers to?

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, find-replace, word-field

By 'the value which the field refers to', I am referring to the text which is between the { }.

**What I have**

Currently, I have many hyperlinks in pages of text like this:

[Testing 123](http://www.google.com) and test [321](http://www.yahoo.com).

**What I hope for**

I want to find and replace every instance of hyperlink field codes with plain text. Specifically, I want the ouput to look like this, in every case: *www.hyperlink.com

**What I have tried**

So far, I have been able to select the field in question, with the hyperlink by putting the following in the 'Find' form: HYPERLINK "*"

However, I am unsure what to put into the replace field in order to update the text as desired, with manually copying each link, then replacing with '^c' in each case. Since I have over 100 pages of link dense text, this is not feasible. I have also tried to use the wildcard and replace with the text: * but the wildcard doesn't seem to recognise that it is algebraically equivelant to the 'find' form's wildcard.

The closest I come is when I try:
Find: HYPERLINK "(*)"
Replace:  \1 
With the option 'use wildcards' checked.

While it moved the hyperlinks to between the ref tags, and banished the HYPERLINK text, the curly brackets { } where kept. So, when I switched out of form field mode (Alt F9) the www.ExampleHyperlink.com dissapears, because it's considered a Form Field thingo!

When I put the curly brackets in the 'find' field, the search fails - so I'm guessing I can't search for them, in order to replace them.

**Possible code?**

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "HYPERLINK ""(*)"""
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

**Response to MacroPod**

Thanks!

Now, I am able to banish the Hyperlink field code, and retain the hyperlink :)

I combine your macro with following macro/step to add the text  and  around each URL:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(<http://*.com>)"
        .Replacement.Text = "<ref>\1</ref>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(<www.*.com>)"
        .Replacement.Text = "<ref>\1</ref>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

It works almost perfectly, except that any part of the URL after the '.com' is missed. For instance, if the URL is: 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/health/about/' then the output is:

```
'<ref> https://www.google.com </ref> /intl/en_us/health/about/'
```

which is not quite what I'm going for because I'd like the second ref tag to come after the last part of the URL. Another issue is that whatever the anchor text was that linked to the URL dissapears. Ideally, it would come immediately prior to the  tag. That's because something is usually linked like this: a [cooldog](http://www.pictureofacooldog.com) is always cool. I really appreciate your assistance. Any idea how I can deal with this?

Comment: You can't do this with only Find/Replace - it's going to require coding. In order to ask this question on Stack Overflow (see the [help]) you will need to have done some of the work (coding) yourself. I recommend you record a macro while executing the Find that works. Use the [edit] link to include that code in your question. We can then show you how to modify it to take the link text out of the Field (*not* form field - that's something else) and delete the field.

Comment: Side note: You can search for field brackets { } using ^d without wildcards. But this will select the entire field, not just the brackets, so doesn't help you in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I have updated my main post with possible code. I haven't learned how to use macro's yet but I found that sample code for a similar problem's solution and I think it may apply. I'll have to learn how to use macros then reapply the solution.

Comment: Do as I suggested and record the macro. What you copied is not useful nor relevant.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Cindy, I've recorded a macro and replaced the old 'possible code' section with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument
  While .Hyperlinks.Count > 0
    .Hyperlinks(1).Range.InsertBefore .Hyperlinks(1).Address
    .Hyperlinks(1).Delete
  Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Macropod! That's almost what I'm looking for. I've tried out this solution and you can see my comments in the main question under the subheading 'response to macropod'

Comment: Whoops, I copied in the wrong code block -  originally I just pasted yours back in! I've updated the main question as appropriate.

Comment: There is no way the code I posted would result in "any part of the URL after the '.com' is missed". If the url is https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/health/about/, then that is what my code would output. In any event, I can't see from your updated question that you're actually using the code I posted. It would also be *really* helpful if you said from the outset what you want to achieve. You apparently want to add <ref> & </ref> tags - which can be achieved via .Hyperlinks(1).Range.InsertBefore "<ref>" & .Hyperlinks(1).Address & "</ref>"

Comment: Thank you so much Macropod! This does what I need! I am so grateful :D